# clip-path does't work in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, clip-path

I have a browser compatibility issue...

I can't figure it out why in **firefox** this doesn't work. 
The mask works fine in **chrome**. I have the feeling this could be related to clip-path, but I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks and please have a look at the demo.

https://codepen.io/davide77/pen/ZopoZJ

```
.mask, .mask2, .mask3 {
    width: 30%;
    height: 10%;
    background: url(http://bae.hypebeast.com/files/2016/04/adidas-originals-tubular-2016-spring-summer-lookbook-33.jpg) center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease-out;
    clip-path: rect(50% 5%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0);
    animation: infinite-translate 20s cubic-bezier(.03,.68,.04,.64);
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

Comment: add the -webkit- one

Comment: I tried, its the first thing I tried. But didn’t work. Did you try yourself? Also Code pen has already all the prefixes build in.